# Is there an industry standard for error messages?

Tags: logging, error-handling, standards

Is there an industry standard for error messages? I hope that it would be from a technology standard organization like W3C or an industry organization like ARTS (Association of Retail Technology Standards).

Answer (score 1):

There are, but they tend to be domain specific. HTTP status codes for instance are defined by IETF [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3). Most standardised services or protocols are likely to consider how implementers should handle errors I would imagine.

I'm not aware of any all encompassing standard for errors though if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what language you're using, each one of them has some sort of standard or best practice. I don't believe there's any standard other than throwing/catching exceptions.